# Reason behind the name **PARITY CHECK MATRIX**

Tags: information-theory

It is easy to understand the name **Generator matrix** because it generates a code **C**. But why the name  **Parity Check matrix** ? i.e,   I want to know the actual reason behind the name **Parity check** (because of behind every name there is a reason).

Comment: The name is explained at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity-check_matrix)."The rows of a parity check matrix are parity checks on the codewords of a code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple check to ensure some binary string hasn't been corrupted is to add the digits using $1+1=0$ and checking to see if it sums to zero or one. This will catch one-off errors and is typically called a parity check. The parity check matrix does this as well and so is named a parity check matrix.